# Eclipse でpoiのファイルが読み込めません。

Tags: eclipse

JAVA　で　Excelを操作しようと思いEclipse2001-06をインストール、poi-5.0.0 をc:\poiにインストール。project　hello の　build path に追加しましたが、"import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;"などをimportしてくれません。(×The package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel is not accesible)[image: buildpath][image: import error]
Mavenを使ってみたり、JDKを　jdk-11.0.12にバージョンアップもしてみましたが、変わりません。
アドバイスをお願いします。

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが、何か参考になるかも。[SikuliX：Apache POIを使用する](https://room.sakura.ne.jp/contents/sikulix_apache-poi), [SikuliX：Apache POIでセルの参照](https://room.sakura.ne.jp/contents/sikulix_apache-poi_001), [SikuliX：Apache POIでExcelシートの追加と値の設定](https://room.sakura.ne.jp/contents/sikulix_apache-poi_002)

Comment: 念のために確認ですが、 「Eclipse2001-06」は「Eclipse2021-06」のミスタイプでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

module-info.javaにrequiresが

```java
modle hello {
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;
}
```

のように記述されているか確認してみてください。

Comment: Eclipse2021-06のミスタイプです。

Comment: module-info.java のrequiresはコメントアウトしていましたが、元に戻しても、やはりうまくいきません。　×org.apatch.ooxml cannot be resolved to a module とエラーが出ます。

Comment: ”org.apatch.ooxml "を"org.apache.poi.ooxml"と直してみてください。エラーメッセージを見る限り"poi"が抜けているようですが、それだけでなく"apatch"のスペルも間違っています。正しくは"apache"です。

Comment: module-info.java のrequiresで、apache -> apatch とミスタイプしてたようです。　初歩的なミスですみませんでした。ありがとうございました。